# Reduce loading on opamp when connecting spectrum analyzer (tinySA)

Tags: signal-processing, spectrum-analyzer

I am trying to measure the spectrum of an output of a signal generator I am building. The output stage of the generator uses the [AD826 op amp](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad826.pdf) in differential amplifier configuration.

The SA I use is [tiny SA](https://www.tinysa.org/wiki/) which states that its input impedance is 50ohms. When this is connected to the output of the opamp, the opamp seems to get loaded and the waveform gets distorted. I have used a small ceramic cap to filter the DC component of the opamp reaching SA.

Why does the SA have such a low input impedance? Being a measuring device I have thought the input impedance would be similar to an oscilloscope.

What are some ways to get around this issue? I can of course use a resistor in series with the SA, but that will attenuate the input to it.

Answer (score 2):

> What are some ways to get around this issue?

Whenever you want to use a SA with a high(ish) impedance output, you need a buffer to isolate the load from the source. The buffer can be a video amplifier meant as a cable driver, or an op-amp with a suitably strong output drive current. The buffer should be designed to have a flat response in the bandwidth of interest for the device under test.

> Why does the SA have such a low input impedance? Being a measuring device I have thought the input impedance would be similar to an oscilloscope.

With high impedance sources, the effects of stray capacitance dominate the response of the circuit, and you'd be measuring the cables instead of the output of the circuit. Oscilloscopes include the buffers but those buffers are so noisy that they'd obliterate the performance you can get out of a spectrum analyzer. To a decent spectrum analyzer, any amplifier is noisy enough to see the difference.